# Is it possible to signal TSTP and then kill it if timeout occurs

Tags: linux, unix, signals, signal-processing

Can I send a signal TSTP to PID , that after a period of time if the process is still "paused" - then kill it ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Should be a simple sequence of 3 operations, methinks: (1) send the TSTP signal to the pid, (2) sleep, and (3) read the third field of `/proc/$pid/stat` to see if it still equals `T`, and if so, send the KILL signal to it.

```
kill -TSTP $pid;
sleep 2;
if [[ "$(awk '{ print($3); };' </proc/$pid/stat;)" == 'T' ]]; then kill -KILL $pid; fi;
```

Useful documentation:

- [`kill(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill)
- [`sleep(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep)
- [`proc(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) (scroll down to the section headed by `/proc/[pid]/stat`)

---

The above code and documentation inhabit the bash universe, but the same operations can be performed from C code almost as easily. It's a little more work, especially to open and read the `/proc/$pid/stat` (or `/proc/$pid/status`) pseudo-file, but the idea is the same. More documentation:

- [`kill(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill)
- [`sleep(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep)
- [`fopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)/[`fread(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread)/[`fscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)/[`fclose(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose); lots of good Stack Overflow threads here, e.g.

  - [How to determine the state of a process (i.e. if it is a zombie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634608/how-to-determine-the-state-of-a-process-i-e-if-it-is-a-zombie)
  - [Getting pid and other process information from /proc/<pid>/status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089956/getting-pid-and-other-process-information-from-proc-pid-status)
  - [how to extract info in linux with a C code from /proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266678/how-to-extract-info-in-linux-with-a-c-code-from-proc)